# Button is disabled when adding background

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using Parse anypic tutorial and I want to create a somehow different UI. But I have some troubles.

So, my ViewController is this :

```
@interface PAPHomeViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) PAPSettingsActionSheetDelegate *settingsActionSheetDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *blankTimelineView;
@end

@implementation PAPHomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"LoadView is called");

    // Present Anypic UI
    [self presentUI];

}

-(void) presentUI {

/*UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
        [backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultAnypic.png"]];
        self.view = backgroundImageView;*/

    // Settings button
    self.settingsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.settingsButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(settingsButtonAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.settingsButton setTitle:@"Settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.settingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    [self.view addSubview:self.settingsButton];
}
```

and its .h file is this :

```
@interface PAPHomeViewController : PAPPhotoTimelineViewController

@end
```

The PAPPhotoTimelineViewController is also a separateViewController, which the Home extends from and it is a tableViewController, which also calls ViewDidLoad.

**The problem :**

With the above Code, I see my button and I can click on my button.

But, if I uncomment stuff for the background, I do see the background, I do see the button, but it cannot be clicked - it is like no touch on the button is identified.

I am also confused, now that I am extending another ViewController which also implements viewDidLoad, why they are both called, in which order etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't assign a new `UIView` to your `self.view`.

Instead of  `self.view = backgroundImageView;`, just add it like a random view.

```
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
```

Doing that, you will follow the right way to add subview: your `backgroundImageView` will be displayed in your view, and your button will be add above it.

Comment: You saved my day! Will accept in a few minutes that it will become eligible.